# ns2 sound design vid and a question

Tags: game

hi guys havent posted here b4 but have been lurking

ive been working on ns2 sounds

here is an interview with me:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjq1zzr8h9o&feature=player_embedded

a question related to the vid, how do u game audio ppl deal with the whole consistency between assets issue? eq matching? do u do it manually? do u use a reference sound?

cheers

simon